# two different permalinks for posts wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

im migrating a drupal website to wordpress, in drupal URL from articles dont have the category but in wordpress i want to implement the category in the url for seo, but my website have a facebook with all links to news and there is like 20.000 articles so its impossible to rewrite each url.

What i need is to have 2 permalinks at same time one is url/%category%/%post% and the other is url/%post%

one solution could be, if category urlgive error redirect to url without category or another solution could be if url/%post% loaded just add in the url the /%category% part too

I have been triying lot of solutions and searched in google but no luck actually

Can someone of you guys help me? thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have tried for example code from this url https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/using-two-permalinks-for-one-post

Comment: Hello kaddath, i dont know what to try im not good developer